# SharePoint Foundation errors on SharePoint server

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

we have a **SharePoint Server**. When I check event viewer i see too many **SharePoint Foundation** errors . Why are there Foundation errors on **Sharepoint 2010 Server**.

Error Event ID's like below:

**7043** (Load control template file /_controltemplates/TaxonomyPicker.ascx failed: Could not load type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.TaxonomyPicker' from assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c'.),

**2138** (The SharePoint Health Analyzer detected a condition requiring your attention.  InfoPath Forms Services forms cannot be filled out in a Web browser because no State Service connection is configured.)

**8059** (Alternate access mappings have not been configured.  Users or services are accessing the site http://proappsrv2 with the URL http://portal.  This may cause incorrect links to be stored or returned to users.  If this is expected, add the URL http://portal as an AAM response URL.  For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=114854"/>)

**5586** : (Unknown SQL Exception 8146 occurred. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.

Procedure proc_GetCurrent has no parameters and arguments were supplied.)

**Have any idea?**

Comment: because I saw in event viever SharePoint Server errors and SharePoint Foundation errors in different categorie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behaviour. Basically, the SharePoint Server is SharePoint Foundation with additional Features (Standard/Publishing/Enterprise etc.) which are enabled based on your license.